# Sum of squares of random variables that satisfy $x_1+\dots+x_n=1$

Tags: random-variables, expectation, sums-of-squares

I am trying to solve the following problem and would very much appreciate some help.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ identically distributed continuous random variables that take values in $(0,1)$ and satisfy the equality $x_1+\dots+x_n=1$ always (not just in expectation). What is the value of $E[x_i^2]$?

In principle, I do not want to pose restrictions on the distribution, although I am mostly interested in the uniform case.

Some initial ideas are that $E(x_i)=1/n$ by symmetry and for the uniform case that:

$\begin{align}
E(x_i^2 \mid x_1+\dots+x_n=1)&=\frac{1}{n} E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \mid x_1+\dots+x_n=1\right)=\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^{1-x_1}\dots\int\limits_0^{1-\sum\limits_1^{n-2}} \sum\limits_1^{n-1}x_i^2+\left(1-\sum\limits_1^{n-1}x_i\right)^2 dx_{n-1}\dots dx_2 dx_1
\end{align}$

But I seem to have serious trouble solving this integral.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: I don't think there is a universal solution to this prolem. Are you actually interested in the case that all $X_i$ are independent and you want to calculate the expectation of $X_i^2$, **conditioned** on $X_1 + \ldots + X_n = 1$? This Problem would be different from what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, it might be what you say, in which case I think the integral should be correct. no? Any idea on that? I am currently trying to work out an inductive solution, without success yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if this integral is correct. My best guess is that the conditional expectation is $\frac{1}{n^2}$, but I don't have any proof yet.

Comment: @Dominik For simplest case I got $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: @Dominik see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a Dirichlet distribution with similar properties, but it is parametrised by $\vec{\alpha}$. In simplest case all $\alpha_i$ = 1, $i=1...n$, $\alpha_0 = n$. Mean and Variance are well-known. $E[X_i] = \frac{1}{n}$, $Var[X_i]=\frac{n-1}{n^2 (n+1)}$. Making $E[X^2_i]$ as sum of Variance and Mean squared, one can arrive to the answer $E[X^2_i]=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$.

Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

More complex case where there is non-trivial $\vec{\alpha}$ could be easily constructed

Comment: Edited, missed 2

Comment: As written in the comments, I suspect the OP actually wants to calculate $E[X_i^2 \mid X_1+\ldots+X_n = 1]$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. uniform random variables.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Indeed what Dominik says is what I had in mind, which in fact is exactly what is described in the Dirichlet distribution mentioned by Severin. I will modify slightly the title and question, not to be misleading. Thanks a lot once again.